# Referring to properties during instantiation

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to create an object in javascript that allows for a function to be called whenever an event has happened. In my program, when an event occurs (identified by a keya), the corresponding function is called.

```
function Foo(dict){
   this.add(dict);

   this.biz = 'world';
};

//add a dictionary to the object
Foo.prototype.add = function(dict){
    for(var k in dict){
        //duplicate key check not needed
        this[k] = function(){
            dict[k]();
        }

        this[k].that = this;
    }
};

//call an event
Foo.prototype.call = function(event){
    this[event]();
};

var foo = new Foo(
{
    //'event key':function(){...}
    //Cannot read property 'biz' of undefined
    'test':function(){alert('hello ' + this.that.biz);}
});

foo.call('test'); //expected output: hello world
```

Is it possible to make a system where someone can make an anonymous function's contents refer to foo's properties, preferably in pure js?

Comment: `this.that` is not defined.  `this.biz` should be.  Also don't prototype `.call` since it is a reserved method in javascript.

Comment: So you're looking to change the scope of anonymous function to the outer function that wraps it? Perhaps [this would be of use](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok first of all - this is your code that works

```
function Foo(dict) {
    this.add(dict);
    this.biz = 'world';
};

//add a dictionary to the object
Foo.prototype.add = function(dict) {
    for (var k in dict) {
        // duplicate key check not needed
        this[k] = dict[k];
    }
};

//call an event
Foo.prototype.execute = function(event) {
    this[event]();
};

var foo = new Foo({
    'test': function() {
        alert('hello ' + this.biz);
    }
});

// here this will be pointing to object foo
// that is the instance of Foo and has property baz
foo.execute('test');
```

And if I understood your second question - the answer is yes. You may pass on object to anonymous function ( *BTW* this is dependency injection ).

```
(function(fooLikeObject) {
    ...
    ...fooLikeObject['test']();
    ...
}(foo));
```